# Can rsync mirror a directory, without following symlinks linking outside the tree?

Tags: rsync, symlink

I want to mirror some home directories to a remote location, but don't want to follow links that point outside the tree. Links pointing with the directories themselves are okay.

I also want the links to be present in the mirror, ie they should be present, only their targets won't be available. It is similar to when you create a tar archive. The links are present when the archive is untarred, with the targets missing.

Is this possible with rsync.

Comment: This is the default behavior. `rsync` does not dereference symlinks without you telling it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use archive mode to achieve this

```
rsync -a
```